# Process id returned by CreateProcess is not there in task manager

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I create a process with Windows API CreateProcess(). Process Id returned by this function is not there in task manager.
When I try to terminate this process using TerminateProcess(). GetLastError() returns 5. Using chrome as sample browser.

My goal is to create a browser process and then shut down the browser after authentication.

My sample code is like this:

```
int main()
{
    wstring app{L"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION browserProcessInfo;
    STARTUPINFO browserStartupInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&browserStartupInfo, sizeof(browserStartupInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&browserProcessInfo, sizeof(browserProcessInfo));
    wstring cmdline;
    cmdline = app + wstring{ { L" --new-windows" } };
    bool bProcessCreated = CreateProcess(NULL,(LPWSTR) (cmdline.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE,     NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS , NULL, NULL, &browserStartupInfo, &browserProcessInfo);
    auto handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, browserProcessInfo.dwProcessId);
    auto terminateStatus = TerminateProcess(handle, 1);
    auto errorNumber = GetLastError();
    CloseHandle(browserProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(browserProcessInfo.hThread);
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but it's `--new-window` (not `--new-windows`).

Comment: A process is destroyed after the final handle to it is closed. If you wish to keep the process object around, don't close the handle. The system automatically closes handles owned by a process when that process terminates, e.g., when control drops off the end of the `main` function.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `OpenProcess()` on the returned PID. `CreateProcess()` also returns the `HANDLE` to the process, and it already has `PROCESS_TERMINATE` permission on it: `TerminateProcess(browserProcessInfo.hProcess, 1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem with `CreateProcess`. `chrome` simply exits pretty much immediately after starting up if Chrome is already running. It simply tells the existing process to create a new window and exits.

Comment: Thank you for help. I quit my chrome browser and used above code I get correct process id after it. 
My contention is to launch edge browser and terminate launched tab of edge when my task is done. Any pointer for this will be very helpful.

Comment: "*My contention is to launch edge browser and terminate launched tab of edge when my task is done*" - web browsers simply don't work that way. There is no guarantee that the final process actually managing the tab will be the same process that you spawned. You should be using the browser's own native APIs to manage the tab you want.

Comment: You might want to look into using Selenium.